# Can I apply a one-way ANOVA and Tukey test to this data?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, data-analysis

The experiment:

Effect of pH on yeast respiration. I tested 5 different pH levels and measured the amount of CO2 produced. The data shows a trend similar to upside down parabola. Would it make sense to apply ANOVA and Tukey, just ANOVA, or is it not really applicable?

Comment: Maybe yes, but I need more information about the experiment. How many measurements at each pH level, and how did they arise? By the 'upside-down parabola' do you mean that. arranging pH levels from low to to high, the lowest and highest pH levels produced the least C02 and middle pH levels the most CO2? (If not that, what do you mean?) Is your goal to show that CO2 varies significantly with pH? (If not that, what is the goal?) Please edit some particulars into your Question, and I will have another look in due course. (Also, if there are not too many observations, can you let me look at them?)

Comment: Hi @BruceET, thank you very much for your answer. I took 5 measurements at each pH level. Yes, the maximum value happened around the middle (not the exact middle) To be honest, I'm not completely sure of my goal, I mainly wonder whether I should do such a test in order to show that I have considered whether my results are significant. If this isn't really necessary I could forego this step. I would be happy to share the data, but ideally if I could do it privately that would be great, just because I don't want my teacher to do a plagiarism check and find my data somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, please see my Answer. I hope it helps you to understand the use of one-way ANOVA and Tukey's HSD. (By the way, even though Tukey is known mainly for his work in statistics, I understand that he began his scientific career as a chemist, so I guess it is appropriate for you to use his method for your data.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clarification in your comment, and with the understanding that the measurements on different pH levels are independent, then you can treat this as a one-way ANOVA. The null hypothesis would be that
all pH levels have the same population mean level of $\text{CO}_2,$
That is $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3 = \mu_4.$ The alternative hypothesis is that not all five of the $\mu_i$ are equal. For a standard one-way ANOVA computation we assume that the carbon dioxide measurements are normally distributed and that all five pH groups have the same population variance.

If $H_0$ is rejected, then we suppose there are some significant differences among the $\mu_i$ and we would like to know the pattern of those differences. Then the Tukey HSD procedure would be one
of several ways to judge which of the $\mu_i$ are different from which other(s).

I don't have the actual data at hand, so here is an illustration
using Minitab software on fake data.
Here are group means and standard deviations of the fake data I used.

```
 Level  N    Mean  StDev 
 pH1    5  60.818  2.375 
 pH2    5  52.098  1.354 
 pH3    5  50.712  2.984 
 pH4    5  60.926  2.793 
 pH5    5  57.926  2.801
```

[image]

From the plots it does seem that there may be significant
differences among the five groups. Here is the ANOVA table.

```
 Source  DF      SS      MS      F      P
 Factor   4  465.76  116.44  18.20  0.000
 Error   20  127.94    6.40
 Total   24  593.70
```

The P-value of the test of $H_0$ is printed as `0.000`,
which means less than 0.0005. So there are there are some
significant differences at any reasonable level of significance.
Because $H_0$ is rejected, it makes sense to use the Tukey method to see where the
significant differences may lie. (If $H_0$ is not rejected
it is not appropriate to use the Tukey method.)

A Tukey HSD procedure gave the following diagram:

```
 Grouping Information Using Tukey Method

      N    Mean  Grouping
 pH4  5  60.926  A
 pH1  5  60.818  A
 pH5  5  57.926  A
 pH2  5  52.098    B
 pH3  5  50.712    B
```

This means that levels pH1, pH4, and pH5 are not deemed significantly different among themselves. Similarly levels pH2 and pH3 are not
deemed significantly different. However the three levels marked A
all deemed significantly different from either of the levels marked B.

Note: Because these are simulated data the actual pattern of population
means is known: $\mu_1 = 60,\, \mu_2 = 54,\, \mu_3 = 50,\, \mu_4 = 53,\, \mu_5 = 58$ and the population standard deviation of each group
is $\sigma = 3.$ Notice that because of random variation, the
order of the $sample$ means is not quite the same as for the known
$population$ means. Also, there are some differences in population
means that were not detected by the Tukey method. With only
five replications per group, no statistical analysis can reliably reclaim the exact pattern of the population means. (In practice
of course, the true population means are not going to be known.)

Comment: Hi Bruce, I had one more question. If my sample sizes are different (I had 3 outliers, 3 of the pHs had one each), can I still apply the ANOVA test and Tukey test?

Comment: Technically, Tukey HSD is only for balanced designs. If you do HSD by hand, for nearly balanced design, use harmonic mean sample size for table of Studentized range. If you've got what you need here, how about clicking checkmark to Accept, and this will go off our list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Hi Bruce, sorry, I'm new to the site, I've accepted it now. I've just found something called the Tukey-Kramer test, which seems to be for unequal samples, would that work?

Comment: Seems so. Never used it. See Wikipedia.

Comment: Alright. I'll look it up some more. Thank you for your help!